# How do I fix the container div that ruined the layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

After I was done working on side bar I wanted to head to the content page to the right so I added a container div that I wanted to set to flex So that I make the two boxes to start styling, but right after adding it, the footer's position is ruined and the side bar isn't taking as much space as it should.

Here's a picture:

[image]

```css
.side-bar {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.side-bar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 0%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.side-bar ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.togglable:hover {
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
}

.togglable:active {
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}

.side-bar ul a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.side-bar h2 {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.task-container {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ToDoList</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a class="cta" href="#"><button>Contact</button></a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="side-bar">
      <ul>
        <li class="togglable"><img src="gym.png" alt="gym" id="gym"><a href="#">Gym</a></li>
        <li class="togglable"><img src="today.png" alt="calendar" id="today"> <a href="#">Today</a></li>
        <li class="togglable"><img src="week.png" alt="calendar" id="week"><a href="#">This Week</a></li>
        <li class="togglable"><img src="month.png" alt="calendar" id="month"> <a href="#">This Month</a></li>
        <h2>Projects : </h2>
        <li id="addPr" class="togglable"><a href="#"><span id="plus-sgn">+</span> Add Project</a></li>
        <!-- <li class="togglable"><img src="checklist.png" alt="checlist" id="list"> <a href="#">Testing</a></li> -->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="task-container">
      <p>Some Text To test the box</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p id="copyright">Copyright © 2021 FaroukHamadi</p>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add width attribute to task-contianer and add your fotter class attribute on your CSS file.

```
.task-container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    
}

.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: That is not a good solution if (and when) the content overflow footer.